# Unable to load webdriver in Katalon - "Could not open/create prefs root node"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, katalon-studio, katalon

> Aug 17, 2021 12:50:57 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences 
> [INFO] Using WebDriverManager to resolve chrome WARNING: Could not
> open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root
> 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.

I tried to replace and update the chrome driver and still encounters the error. Whenever  I'm updating the driver I get the above error message.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8146335) and [this](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8139507)

> 1. This happens because the JRE installer no longer creates the HKLM Prefs entry. JRE version 1.7.0_13 and before created the entry (same rights, also UAC enabled), version 1.7.0_21 (and 1.8.0) stopped doing that. Did not test it on 1.7.0_15 and 1.7.0_17.
> 2. The warning makes no sense as the source code is NOT explicitly accessing the system root, only the user root.
> 3. I think it should be valid to run java with UAC enabled.

So try **upgrading** the Java version or running Katalon as **administrator**.